# Flow Sessions we're not provided for following transaction participants - Corda 4

Tags: corda

i am getting this error in corda 4 Flow sessions were not provided for the following transaction participants I don't want this participant to sign my transaction then why I got this error?
I have two parties defined in my state class and I want only one of them of to sign the transaction, and I didn't created the flow session for the other party.
Please help to resolve this.

Comment: It was working fine in corda 3.3.

Comment: Hi Viraj, can you update this question with the code that causes the error? Does this happen when invoking CollectSignaturesFlow/FinalityFlow or something else?

Comment: Yes in both flows I have not created this parties session I think that's why it gives the error.

Answer (score 1):

In Corda 4, you are required to pass `FinalityFlow` a list of sessions that includes all of the transaction's participants, so that the transaction can be distributed accordingly.

Just because someone is in this list of participants, it does not make them a required signer. The required signers are determined by the public keys listed on the transaction's commands.

Comment: Hi Joel if I do this then do i need to define a responder flow for the party that doesn't has to sign because I am getting an error currently if I don't do so I have asked it on slack

Comment: does this mean from corda 4, required signers and flow session list should be same? if I keep this way i am getting "CordaRuntimeException: Don't know about ..." error, pls let me know how do I fix this?