# Unable to Create Corda Transaction with self node using corda 4.0

Tags: corda

I want to create transaction with self node using corda 4.0 .

I used sample IOU example for this and added my changes in ExampleFlow as shown in below code .
 https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/tree/release-V4/java-source.

But its not allowing to create transaction with self node.

also I followed/implemented the answers from this [Corda 4 - Single Party Transaction Failed to Commit to Ledger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54875913/corda-4-single-party-transaction-failed-to-commit-to-ledger)

but it didnt work out.

I made Only changes in ExampleFlow as shown below  / Rest of the code from iOU example is same.

Please help.

```
@Suspendable
override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
// Obtain a reference to the notary we want to use.
val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]

// Stage 1.
progressTracker.currentStep = GENERATING_TRANSACTION
// Generate an unsigned transaction.
val iouState = IOUState(iouValue, serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first(), otherParty)
val txCommand = Command(IOUContract.Commands.Create(), listOf(ourIdentity.owningKey))
val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
        .addOutputState(iouState, IOU_CONTRACT_ID)
        .addCommand(txCommand)

// Stage 2.
progressTracker.currentStep = VERIFYING_TRANSACTION
// Verify that the transaction is valid.
txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

// Stage 3.
progressTracker.currentStep = SIGNING_TRANSACTION
// Sign the transaction.
val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

// Stage 5.
progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISING_TRANSACTION
// Notarise and record the transaction in both parties' vaults.
return subFlow(FinalityFlow(partSignedTx,emptyList()))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is because you are using the **otherparty** in the state:

```
val iouState = IOUState(iouValue, serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first(), otherParty)
```

Corda 4 requires that all participants flowsession must be provided in the `FinalityFlow`, so that the state information could be distributed properly.

Refer here for more
[Flow Sessions we're not provided for following transaction participants - Corda 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54777158/flow-sessions-were-not-provided-for-following-transaction-participants-corda)

Comment: Also please note that the repository you are pointing to is deprecated. Please consider using this instead: https://github.com/corda/samples